# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redefine class constant Memcached::RES_BAD_KEY_PROVIDED in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, macos, memcached

**Environment:** PHP7.1.0.

I already installed **libMemcached**, I want to install *php-memcached extension on Mac*, download from :

https://github.com/rlerdorf/php-memcached

I add:

```
 "extension=/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20160303/memcached.so"
```

into `php.ini`, I got errors.

I hope resolve this?

**php --ini error.png :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I switch memcache extension to https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached and solved now ...